# parsing geojson using jackson

Tags: java, jackson, geojson

I have some GeoJSON which corresponds to a PostGIS Point object.

Here is an example:

```
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-397408.355686851020437,7575590.819041009992361]}
```

I tried to parse this into a postgis point object in Java by doing:

```
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                Point coors = null;
                 try {
                     coors = mapper.readValue(str, Point.class);
                } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I get the following JsonMappingException:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "x": org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params) vs org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:346)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:167)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findTypedValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2820)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2719)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1854)
    at dao.impl.PostGisDaoImpl.getOsmPoiNodes(PostGisDaoImpl.java:53)
    at service.OsmDBService.main(OsmDBService.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "x": org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params) vs org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getSetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:654)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:583)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:341)
    ... 8 more
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?
Thanks

EDIT:

New Exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "x": org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params) vs org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:346)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:167)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:596)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.resolve(BeanDeserializer.java:379)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._resolveDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:438)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:383)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:167)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.findTypedValueDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2820)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2719)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1854)
    at dao.impl.PostGisDaoImpl.getOsmPoiNodes(PostGisDaoImpl.java:53)
    at service.OsmDBService.main(OsmDBService.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "x": org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params) vs org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.POJOPropertyBuilder.getSetter(POJOPropertyBuilder.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:654)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:583)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createDeserializer(StdDeserializerProvider.java:432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider._createAndCache2(StdDeserializerProvider.java:341)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: You might want to share what your `Point` class looks like.

Comment: I am using the PostGIS Point class which I don't have access to:
http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/javadoc/org/postgis/Point.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue is that it sees both the definition of the variable an the setter method for the variable so `double x;` and `setX(double x)` as it being defined twice. You need to tell it to pick one or another by adding the [`@XmlAccessorType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessorType.html) at the top of your class and setting it to [`XmlAccessType.FIELD`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html) or whichever you prefer it to use. For example:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Point {
  ...
}
```

---

If you are using [`Point`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/javadoc/org/postgis/Point.html) from here it is different than what I expected. It is because it actually has two set methods: [`void setX(double x)`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/javadoc/org/postgis/Point.html#setX%28double%29) and [`void setX(int x)`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/javadoc/org/postgis/Point.html#setX%28int%29)

So in this case you want field access. Still looking to see how to set it programmatically instead of annotation.

**UPDATE:** I think in this case your best bet is to create a wrapper for the [`Point`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/javadoc/org/postgis/Point.html) class that you can then pull the point back out of. So something like:

```
public class MyPoint {

    private String type;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Point point;

    public MyPoint(){
        this.point = new Point();
    }

    public double[] getCoordinates(){
        return new double[] {this.point.getX(), this.point.getY()};
    }

    public void setCoordinates(double[] x){
        if (x.length == 2){
            this.point.setX(x[0]);
            this.point.setY(x[1]);
        }
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

And then change your code to:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Point coors = null;
 try {
     MyPoint mine = mapper.readValue(str, MyPoint.class);
     coors = mine.point;
} catch (JsonParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Maybe there is a better way, but this should work.

**EDIT:**

This is the test I ran to see if this worked:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-397408.355686851020437,7575590.819041009992361]}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Point coors = null;
     try {
         MyPoint mine = mapper.readValue(str, MyPoint.class);
         coors = mine.point;
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     System.out.println(coors);
}
```

And the output that I get:

```
POINT(-397408.355686851 7575590.81904101)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I just tried this but the same exception occurs.

Comment: Was the message exactly the same? Can you edit it into your question also?

Comment: @sam Give that a try. Basically I added the `@JsonIgnore` annotation, and added the type field in and that works in my tests. I can't help but feel there has to be a better way to do this?

Comment: Ok, added that annotation.

There are no exceptions now, but the Point created only has 0,0 for x and y

Comment: You actually need two annotations: the method you do want to use needs `@JsonProperty`. Reason for this is that by default Jackson assumes that your `@JsonIgnore` indicates that you just want to altogether ignore property (which makes it easy not having to add annotations in both setter and getter). But in this case you only want to ignore one specific method; and hence need to "split" accessors.

Comment: @StaxMan if he sets it up just like the example, it should work. The `Point point` is public and does not have a getter and setter method. You are correct if he was able to annotate the `Point` class but it is part of a separate library that he cannot modify. That is why I suggested a wrapper class that maps to the JSON and sets everything correctly in a new instance of `Point`. Then grab the instance back out afterwards.

Comment: @sam I am not sure what is happening. With the `MyPoint` I provided above, and my test which I just edited in it works.

Comment: @jschoen I should have added my comment on the question -- agreed it was bit misplaced. But see my other answer on mix-in annotations, for an alternate solution, since they are useful for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Exception points out the problem, which you can see from the Javadoc you linked to. There are two alternate setters:

```
void setX(double x)
void setX(int x)
```

and Jackson doesn't want to guess which one it should try to use. Having a field and setter is NOT problematic; methods (setter) have precedence over fields.

Since you can't modify `Point`, you will probably want to use [mix-in annotations](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/08/entry_305.html).
Or custom deerializer if you prefer.

Comment: Never heard of Mix-ins that is pretty nice and nice write up about it too.

Comment: Yeah it's too bad that mix-in annotations are not more widely known. It is something that Jackson came up with quite a while ago, and would be nice to see for other libs too: something that achieves the same even if not implemented exactly the same way.